# Monitoring fragmented packets after reassembly

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, network-monitoring

Using network monitoring and packet capturing tools (like Wireshark or Tshark)
I can see fragmented packet.

How can I see these packets after reassembly?

These packets do not reach application layer, what are possible reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Basically in Wireshark I would use "Follow TCP stream" on the right mouse button menu or from the Analyse toolbar. Additionally reassembled packets are shown as an additional tab in the Packets pane (see https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvReassemblySection.html).

As for the packets not reaching the application you might want to check the firewall settings and in some cases the packets might be discarded by the kernel due to low memory buffers.